# Alert() call in jQuery not displaying, called from within a JsTree

Tags: jquery

I don't see the alert in this code. It is possibly a typo because i traced the code as it was executing and I receive the correct "nodeInfo" the alert just doesn't come up.

```
    function loadTree(jsonData){
        var treeInfo = attachTree(stageTreeData(getJson(jsonData)));
        $("#apple_tree").jstree({                           
        "json_data": {"data": treeInfo},    
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ]
        }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
           // `data.rslt.obj` is the jquery extended node that was clicked
           var nodeInfo = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
           alert(nodeInfo);
       });
    }
```

Thanks for any and all help!!

EDIT #1 Changed the code structure:

```
function loadTree(jsonData){
    var treeInfo = attachTree(stageTreeData(getJson(jsonData)));
    $("#apple_tree").jstree({                           
        "json_data": {"data": treeInfo},    
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ]
    });
    $("#apple_tree").bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
        // `data.rslt.obj` is the jquery extended node that was clicked
        var nodeInfo = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
        alert(nodeInfo);
    });
}
```

Still no luck on the alert() showing up.

Comment: "i traced the code as it was executing and I receive the correct "nodeInfo" the alert just doesn't come up" --- It's not possible

Comment: In Chrome you can do it, believe me the debugger is really good. = ))

Comment: I know how to work with debugger. I say - if that code is executed - you should see alert. It's not possible that you don't see it. Is the line with alert executed (when you're debugging)? Any console errors?

Comment: No errors, the line is executed, I placed breakpoints before and after it and they both activated. Weird right?? Not sure what is up.

Comment: uhm, "I placed breakpoints before and after it and they both activated" - I don't see any possible place for a breakpoint after. What if you go step by step and get exactly to the alert call? PS: still - what you say doesn't sound possible.

Comment: You can place a breakpoint at the closing brace.

Comment: as I said - what if you perform it step by step. Anyway - please reproduce it on jsfiddle.net. It's not any helpful now. PS: "You can place a breakpoint at the closing brace." --- debugger doesn't know at which brace - curly or parentheses. And they are different breakpoints.

Comment: Ill expand the code to expose the possible bug in the curly / parenthesis. Thanks very much

Comment: instead of that you could reproduce that on jsfiddle. But it's your issue :-)

Comment: Im not sure how to add a resource on JsFiddle like jstree, it does not have a URL.

Comment: "it does not have a URL" -- what does that mean? You cannot upload it somewhere?

Comment: Yes that is what i mean, I dont have a server available...

Comment: omg, is it a joke that webdeveloper doesn't know where to host its script? https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Haha, yeah sometimes your a newb. No reason to be impolite.

Comment: you spent **2 hours** to find a place for sharing your code... o_O

Comment: I already fixed the problem, Im on to the next one...